# Como se hace para intercambiar columnas en numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Hola consulta con Python - Numpy para intercambia las columnas 1 y 2 en una matriz, la matriz dada:

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

Salida:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Esperado:

```
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [7, 6, 8]])
```

Como seria? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```py
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
a = a[:,[1,0,2]]
print(a)

# output: 
[[1 0 2]
 [4 3 5]
 [7 6 8]]
```

Lo que hace es una copia del mismo numpy array, pero hace un swapping o intercambio de columnas, usando todas las rows (':') y especifica el orden de los índices.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._